# She washed the dishes in the sink in the kitchen

Tags: grammar

1. She washed the dishes in the sink in the kitchen.

Does 'in the kitchen' modify 'the sink' ? Or does 'in the kitchen' modify 'washed'? Is 'in the kitchen' an adverbial phrase or an adjective phrase? Or can it be both?

Comment: There are several interpretations.  "In the kitchen" could be adjectival, modifying "sink"[1], or modifying "dishes in the sink"[2]. or it could be adverbial, modifying the sentence "she washed the dishes in the sink"[3].  [1] tells which sink was used; [2] tells which dishes got washed, and [3] tells where the dish-washing event took place.

Comment: Good question +1.

Comment: Regardless of the *syntax*, there can only be one essential *meaning* that I can think of. She was standing in the kitchen and washing the dishes that were in the sink there. Now, whether or not she washed the dishes in the *kitchen sink* (as opposed to a detached sink that had been carried into the kitchen) is another matter . . .

Answer (score -2):

This can be solved by writing the sentence in a more grammatically correct way - She washed the dishes in the kitchen sink.
And by the way, "he" can do it too!

Comment: The OP posed four questions. I don't think you have answered any of them.

Comment: Are you suggesting the original is ungrammatical?